# How to make Intro page like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Here I am using introduction_screen plugin.

### In this problem, I want the same Ui which is my first image, but my second image is being created as it is.

### Here I want dots in middle after image and next text on bottom with arrow which should be work for next intro page

How to make it

This is my intro page code.
I am using introduction_screen plugin

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:introduction_screen/introduction_screen.dart';

class OnBoardingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnBoardingPageState createState() => _OnBoardingPageState();
}

class _OnBoardingPageState extends State<OnBoardingPage> {
  final introKey = GlobalKey<IntroductionScreenState>();

  void _onIntroEnd(context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage()),
    );
  }


  Widget _buildImage(String assetName, ) {
    return Image.asset('assets/$assetName',);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const bodyStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0);

    const pageDecoration =  PageDecoration(
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
      bodyTextStyle: bodyStyle,
      bodyPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0),
      pageColor: Colors.white,
      imagePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: IntroductionScreen(
          key: introKey,
          globalBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          pages: [
            PageViewModel(
              decoration: pageDecoration,
              title: "Fractional shares",
              body:
              "Instead of having to buy an entire share, invest any amount you want.",
              image: _buildImage('intro_s1.png'),

            ),
            PageViewModel(
              title: "Learn as you go",
              body:
              "Download the Stockpile app and master the market with our mini-lesson.",
              image: _buildImage('intro_s1.png'),
              decoration: pageDecoration,
            ),
            PageViewModel(
              title: "Kids and teens",
              body:
              "Kids and teens can track their stocks 24/7 and place trades that you approve.",
              image: _buildImage('intro_s1.png'),
              decoration: pageDecoration,
            ),


          ],
          onDone: () => _onIntroEnd(context),
          next: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          done: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
          controlsMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          controlsPadding: kIsWeb
              ? const EdgeInsets.all(12.0)
              : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0),
          dotsDecorator: const DotsDecorator(
            size: Size(10.0, 10.0),
            color: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
            activeSize: Size(22.0, 10.0),
            activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
            ),
          ),
          dotsContainerDecorator: const ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.black87,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
      body: const Center(child: Text("This is the screen after Introduction")),
    );
  }
}
```

I want looks like this [image]

but it is becoming like this
[image]

Comment: you mean onborading? pages

Comment: @ArbiterChil yes mean was this.

Answer (score 0):

change `black87` to `white` in this section of your code.

```
dotsContainerDecorator: const ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.black87,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))
```